# ¿Como establecer la fecha actual como fecha máxima de un campo date en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
let today = new Date();
let dd = today.getDate();
let mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

let minimum = "2018-01-01";

let search_date = document.getElementById("search_date");

search_date.max = today;
search_date.min = minimum;
```

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control disablecopypaste" name="search_date" id="search_date" placeholder="Ingrese la fecha a buscar" required>
```

El atributo de mínimo funciona bien. El atributo de máximo solo valida el año y los meses, ya que, aunque el `today` sea 2018-03-14 puede elegir hasta el 31 de marzo.

¿Como validar que el límite de la fecha sea el **día actual**?

NOTA: si coloco la fecha directo como es el caso de minimum, funciona perfectamente

--- ACTUALIZACIÓN ---

```
alert(today)
// 2018-03-14
```

Comment: Hola! ¿Qué te sale si imprimes o colocas en alert() la variable today? De hecho... sería prudente que usaras otro nombre de variable para ello, ya que primero declaras today como objeto Date y luego, le asignas un valor de cadena...

Comment: @quinqui actualizado

Comment: Pues no le veo error, salvo que como te digo, siga creyendo que today es tipo Date, al momento de asignarla al max de search_date. ¿Podrías verificar qué te arroja el `typeof today`?

Comment: primero Date luego string

Comment: Mmmh, lo he probado en el Tryit de w3schools, y me ha funcionado... siempre y cuando ejecute todo ese código durante el evento onload del body del documento. ¿Cuándo estás ejecutando este código?

Comment: He puesto el código como ejecutable y parece funcionar sin problemas (al menos en Chrome)

Comment: El codigo funciona, el problema es la fecha, tendria que ser el limite el dia actual, pero solo limita el mes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede asignar la fecha en el `input` sin necesidad de darle formato. Para esto se usa el atributo `valueAsDate`. Hacemos una función que si la fecha del `input` es menor al mínimo permitido, se ponga en el mínimo, y si es mayor al máximo del intervalo, se ponga en máximo.

La función `validar` es llamada cuando el valor del `input` cambia, es decir, en el evento `onchange`.

El único problema con esto, es que al cambiar la fecha mediante el teclado, por ejemplo, está en *28 de Febrero del 2017*, al tocar la flecha de arriba del teclado, pasa a ser una fecha inválida (*29/02/2017*). En este caso, los operadores de comparación se encargarán de determinar si elegir la fecha mínima o máxima.

Es decir, que debido a la mala implementación del `input` en el navegador, no es posible incrementar al día siguiente o anterior mediante el teclado, y no pasa al *1 de Marzo*.

```js
function validar()
{
  if(fecha.valueAsDate>intervalo[1]){fecha.valueAsDate=intervalo[1]}
  if(fecha.valueAsDate<intervalo[0]){fecha.valueAsDate=intervalo[0]}
}
var intervalo = [ new Date("1/1/2018"), new Date() ]
fecha.valueAsDate = intervalo[1]
fecha.onchange = validar
```

```html
<input type="date" id="fecha" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validarlo de la siguiente manera (ya optimizas tu el código después):

```js
let today = new Date();
let dd = today.getDate();
let mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

let minimum = "2018-01-01";

let search_date = document.getElementById("search_date");

search_date.max = today;
search_date.min = minimum;

function valida(fecha) {
  let today = new Date();
  let dd = today.getDate();
  let mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }

  today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  if (fecha > today) {
    document.getElementById("search_date").value = today;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control disablecopypaste" name="search_date" id="search_date" placeholder="Ingrese la fecha a buscar" required onchange="valida(this.value)">
```